# At which point does the physical change in evolution occur?

Tags: evolution, macroevolution

So you go from homo erectus to human for example. At which point do the actual physical changes take place. Does it happen in the embryo, is it only a change in DNA at a very early stage in the new animal or does it happen when the animal is growing or has fully grown?

And which body parts change first, what is the order of sequence?

Comment: You've essentially asked, "[Which came first, the chicken or the egg?](https://www.science.org.au/curious/earth-environment/which-came-first-chicken-or-egg)" Obviously reptiles laid eggs, so eggs. But the first *chicken egg*, was it laid by a chicken? Chicken first? Or did the not-quite-a-chicken ancestor lay the not-quite-a-chicken-egg that became the first chicken? Egg first? The point is, either way, the two of them, the ancestor and the chicken, had to be extremely, exceedingly, unimaginably similar in appearance. That's the point at which physical changes in evolution take place.

Comment: It’s not clear to me what you are asking. Changes in DNA are required for changes in the organism, which goes through an embryonic stage. Are you asking at what stages or tissues a mutation in DNA can occur that will produce a heritable change in an animal? And the answer to the last question surely depends on the nature of the overall evolutionary change and even then can vary. And please finish the [Tour] to find out how this site works, and the Help on asking questions.

Comment: @anongoodnurse "Had to" is a tiny bit too certain.  Punctuated Equilibrium events do happen occasionally.  It's just sort of like winning the lottery.  More like "the two of them, the ancestor and the chicken, were so likely to be extremely, exceedingly, unimaginably similar in appearance that we can basically assume they were in any case where we don't have evidence to the contrary."

Comment: @Jeremiah - I agree that some changes occur suddenly, but those are so rare as to easily allow a "had to". The difference between the red jungle fowl and a domesticated chicken is that one gene changed enough to allow a harder shell. Look at a [picture of the red jungle fowl](https://ebird.org/species/redjun) and tell me it doesn't look like a handsome rooster to you. The mutation, btw, occurred several times in different locations. No one is recorded to have exclaimed, "Omg! A CHICKEN!"

Comment: @anongoodnurse Yeah I'm not really commenting on the chicken in particular.  The thing is though that a red junglefowl is just a wild chicken.  Domestic chickens are a subspecies of Gallus gallus.  They diverged from junglefowl solely as a consequence of domestication.  There was never some species of wild chickens unless you are talking about junglefowl.  Now, could the green and red junglefowl have gotten their different colored feathers all at once?  Yeah.  Color changes are one of the more common single generation shifts so it's totally feasible.  Did they?  Probably not.

Comment: @Jeremiah - I believe you and I are pretty much in agreement overall. I agree about feather coloration, but (always a but) having raised many breeds, especially rare breeds, of chickens, those feathers don't look at all different from some of the chickens I raised, especially the crosses.

Comment: I'm not sure where any of the "buts" are coming from if I'm being honest. I wasn't attacking your comment even from the start, just pointing out that punctuated equilibrium events occur and that evolution isn't always totally gradual. Like most species, the chicken probably has some stutters and jumps in its history if you go back far enough. An egg probably did hatch at some point that looked very different from its mom.  What this change was and whether it was in a junglefowl or before is kind of immaterial. I don't think we really disagree on anything. I was just clarifying a generalization

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat unclear what this question is asking, but it seems like it assumes that evolution is some sort of linear process, which it isn't.  You may as well be asking "at what point did latin turn into french".  People tend to overthink evolution, largely due to intentional efforts to obscure its simplicity by certain groups and individuals, but it's a very simple process at its core.  Evolution is just the name we give to the change that happens when selection acts on variable populations with transmissible traits.  If you have a mechanism for generating variability, like mutation and crossover, a mechanism for allowing traits to persist across generations, like heritability, and a selective mechanism, like natural selection, the population will change over time as new traits are generated and the ones that are selected against are pruned off while those that are selected for increase in frequency.

This isn't limited to biological systems.  Languages evolve over time, and are even mapped out using the same cladistic methods that biologists use.  Genetic algorithms like differential evolution are used to find the optimal solutions to complex optimization problems.  Even internet memes undergo a diversification and selection process that maps quite well onto biological evolution.  Any time you have diversity, transmission, and selection, you get the process we have come to call evolution.

Looking at it like this, you can see that it doesn't make sense to ask "what changes first" because that will be radically different from instance to instance.  The diversity generation processes in biological evolution are random.  Nonrandom selection will then prune that down, but what it gets to work with in what order is largely down to a roll of the dice.

There are some general tendencies in this regard.  Changes effecting non-vital systems, for example, are less likely to be deleterious in a way that would cause them to be selected against than more drastic changes, and so more "good" ones would likely pop up before a "good" change happens to show up for something easier to break.  Polygenic traits that are impacted by a number of different genes are also more prone to drift, since a change in any one of those factors will likely not break things too much when others can pick up the slack.  So one could predict that, say, changes to a polygenic, largely aesthetic trait like hair or skin color, would happen more often than something more impactful like a change in skeletal structure or an organ moving to a new spot, not because the mutations themselves are necessarily any more likely but because they are less likely to be selected out when they happen if they aren't immediately beneficial.

This doesn't necessarily help when talking about what changes happened "first" in the transition from one organism to another though.  This is partly because defining when such a change starts is usually very fuzzy, since evolution is generally a very slow, smooth process.  However, there are those occasions where a population diverges very rapidly into something that it makes sense to differentiate into two different species, sometimes in one generation.  On these occasions, it does make sense to talk about a "first" change in the evolution of that species.  The problem is that sudden, all at once changes that actually benefit the organism are extremely rare, and so are the exact opposite sort of "first" changes one would predict using the statistical logic above.  If the new species diverged from it's parent species slowly, but experienced some incidence of punctuated equilibrium during that process, that instance of punctuated equilibrium, statistically, probably happened later than a bunch of smaller mutations.  However, if that punctuated equilibrium event is what caused the speciation event to occur, then the least likely mutation to be first is, in fact, first.

Humans do have evidence of punctuated equilibrium events in our history.  One especially well documented one is the fusion of human chromosome 2, changing our chromosome number from the 24 seen in chimps and our common ancestor to the 23 we have today.  The markers of this fusion are very obvious (it has 2 centromeres) and this simply couldn't have happened gradually.  At some point, a parent with 24 chromosome pairs had a kid with 23, and that kid was probably distinctly different from their parent, though we don't know how.  If that led to a speciation event (actually pretty likely since it would problematize breeding with the parent species) that would be the "first" mutation in that new species history.  If it didn't, then there were probably a million virtually undetectable changes to stuff like fingernail growth and nose hair texture before anything big like that happened.

Comment: Human chromosome 2 doesn't actually have 2 centromeres. It has what appears to be remnants of a centromere, and genetic material identical to telomeres in the middle, whereas in "normal" chromosomes, the telomeres are only at the ends, suggesting a fusion (along with banding patterns). But this is a nice explanation, much better than my comment.

Comment: Good call.  I didn't really mean two functioning centromeres, but that's definitely worth clarifying, as two actual functional centromeres would make the chromosome nonfunctional and I don't want anyone repeating stuff that is going to get them hammered later when some creationist drills down into the details.  Thanks!

Comment: Pedantically, selection is not necessary for evolution to occur, though it is sufficient when combined with heritable differences in fitness and in most cases the more "interesting" contributor to evolution.

Comment: True, and I actually find nondarwinian mechanisms of evolution to be plenty interesting, but I thought diving into the weeds of genetic drift and spandrels and heffalumps and woozles was going to be more confusing than helpful when someone was asking a question like this one. Maybe the blue jolly ranchers are gone because they are your favorite, or maybe it's just because you happened to grab all the blue candies, but if someone still doesn't accept that a bag can be cleared of blue candies through random grabbing if you put the non-blue ones back, the second point just muddies the first.